# Defining a function of matrices

Tags: matrix, core-language

I am translating my code from Python to *Mathematica*. How can I define a function similar to the following:

```python
def getF(csi, a, b):
    csiInv = linalg.inv(csi)
    valueF = csiInv.dot(a).dot(csiInv).dot(b)
    traceF = valueF.trace()
    return 0.5 * traceF
```

where `csi, a, b` are all matrices? I know that in *Mathematica* the usual way of defining things, i.e. ":=", works only with one line following the ":=" sign, but if this was true then I wouldn't be able to "define" a similar funciton in *Mathematica*.

Comment: [Module](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html) and/or [CompoundExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html)?

Comment: I think Module can be the way to do that, so I have tried with the following code:

Comment: getF[csi_, a_, b_] :=
  Module[ {csiInv, valueF, TraceF, Csi, A, B},
     Csi = csi;
              A = a;
              B = b;
                     csiInv = Inverse[csi];
     valueF = csiInv.a.csiInv.b;
     TraceF = Trace[valueF];
     Return[0.5*traceF]

Comment: However, if I try with a simple example, like: F = getF[IdentityMatrix, IdentityMatrix, IdentityMatrix];  I do not get any result...how is that possible?

Comment: i posted as an answer what i think is the corrected version of your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cleaning up the example in the comments:

```
ClearAll[getF, a, b, csi, csiInv, valueF, TraceF]
getF[csi_, a_, b_] :=  
  Module[{csiInv, valueF, TraceF}, 
    csiInv = Inverse[csi]; 
    valueF = csiInv.a.csiInv.b; TraceF = Tr[valueF]; 
    Return[0.5*TraceF]]
getF[IdentityMatrix[3], IdentityMatrix[3], IdentityMatrix[3]]
(* 1.5 *)
```

Or, better yet,

```
getF2[csi_, a_, b_] := Module[{csiInv = Inverse[csi]}, .5 Tr[csiInv.a.csiInv.b]]
getF2[IdentityMatrix[3], IdentityMatrix[3], IdentityMatrix[3]]
(* 1.5 *)
```

Notes: (1) [Tr](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tr.html) is the function you need for the trace of a matrix, not [Trace](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trace.html), (2) you need to use `IdentityMatrix[n]` instead of `IdentityMatrix`.